# How to customise AWS Load Balancer server error message?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing

My site uses AWS LB and Cloudfront. For a non-existent URL, example - 
http://mysite-domain/somepath/file-doesnot-exist.jpg

on browser screen it returns:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /somepath/file-doesnot-exist.jpg was not found on this server.
**Apache/2.2.27 (Amazon) Server at my-some-lb-name.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com Port 80**
```

I don't like the load balance server name being revealed. How can I customize this "not found" screen?

That at least it doesn't show the server name part in the last line.

Comment: @BMW: re your edit, we try not to use inline code formatting for names of technologies. Use this for small code samples that are mentioned in a sentence, class/var names, or console I/O. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you would be able to handle this at the load balancer. It sounds like you just need to configure a 404 page on your actual web servers.

Comment: yep. This is coming from the webserver. It'd be odd for the load balancer to alter content.